# ThreeTenBP DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, threetenbp

I am trying to convert a date String from the server to dateTime with **ThreeTenBP**.  My method looks like this:

```
String toDateTime(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("M/d/yyyy h:mm a").toFormatter();
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeWithZone = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    return dateTimeWithZone.toString();
}
```

However, I get an exception:

> DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-07-21T09:26:06.260-05:00' could not
>   be parsed at index 4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, look at your pattern and look at the input string...

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern begins with "M/" which would indicate the month. Your actual date string begins with "2015-" which is obviously the year. Actually that date looks like it's in ISO 8601 format and a pattern like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" would match.

Comment: After trying your pattern, I get this error: `Text '2015-07-21T09:26:06.260-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19`

Comment: Just updated the answer. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for date pattern docs.

Comment: Ah, that nasty colon character in the timezone. Needs "X" instead of "Z" to parse that. I think that's only available with Java 7 and newer. Not sure they backported that with ThreeTenBP. Good luck!